# Could not load file or assembly 'someProject' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: dependencies, assemblies

I am stuck with one asp.net error.
My application work fine on development and test environemnt. But on production it give me following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'someProject' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just delete the bin folder and then agian copy it. Now, it is working...

Comment: This might help a small percent of the population:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309555/1464716

Answer (score 16):

Go to Sysinternals and download Process Monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Then start it up, filter thread and registry actions away. Clear contents. Run your app and get the error, and then stop the collection in process monitor. Now search for an ACCESS DENIED status, and you'll be able to see the exact file that's causing troubles, as well as the user account trying to get access.

Comment: I was having an `Access denied` problem, and doing this let me found the issue as a `PATH NOT FOUND` event targetting some library of mine in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8ef518fa\1fb2943c\Backend\Backend.dll` so I ended up using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809144/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-someproject-or-one-of-its-dependencies-access#answer-7823546

Comment: My issue was access to folders: C:\Users\{{username}}\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files


Procmon greatly helped me.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Give full permissions to the running user or group (like MACHINE\users group or DOMAIN\domain users) in

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Use your target .net version number instead of v4.0.30319 if it's other than .net 4.0.

Comment: Doing simply this didn't work for me, I had to set the permissions, then delete all folders underneath `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder, and then it worked

Answer (score 3):

After deploying a new Web API project to our web farm, one of our web servers was malfunctioning and giving the error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.`

It turns out the folder hosting the Web API site was missing permissions for **`IIS_IUSRS`**.  Adding the user with `Read`, `Read & execute`, and `List folder contents` permissions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case by changing application pool identity from **applicationpoolidentity** to **network service** it works hope this will help you.

Comment: Even when I know to check for this one, I still forget... Thank you for the reminder. This is probably the most important step in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the server user has access to the directory where your assemblies are located.

Comment: what do you mean by server user?

Comment: The user context you asp.net application is running under.

Comment: it is actually integrated security option. when ever user hit site. it will ask domain\username and password...

Comment: I believe that is just used to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an incorrectly configured server.

First, verify that the assembly does indeed exist.

Second, verify that your worker process account has access to it.

Comment: i think it exist, i deployed it. all dll are in the bin folders.

Comment: That's only half of it.  You have to verify that the worker process has access to it.  Basically, start going through the IIS settings and compare your production box to the staging box.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your Application Pool. My web site was thrown this error on my development laptop.  It configure my 'Application' off of the Default Web site to use the wrong Application Pool. The Application Pool that I needed 32-bit Applications enabled.  The error was reporting my older 32-bit DLL failed to load.