# Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.11.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, iis, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

So I have created a NuGet Server via an ASP.Net Web Application following this tutorial: http://nugetserver.net/ which is hosted in IIS. I have placed the files on my D: drive on my server along with my packages.

**IIS Sites Virtual Path:**[image]

I get the following **error** when I navigate to the url:
[image]

In case the picture is not clear enough, please see below:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.11.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here is my project's **web.config** file along with my **publishing profile**:
[image][image]

My target .NET Framework version is 4.6 but the packages themselves are those of an earlier version of .NET. Could this be the problem? I took the project folder and put it on my physical path on my local machine and it works just fine when I run the project in debug mode. Please see screenshot below:

**NOTE:** I have to hide the package names due to organizational confidentiality policies.[image]

I am pointing to these package files:

```
D:\Backup\Dropbox\vox_server_01\nuget\Packages
```

The reason I am creating this NuGet server is because the existing one is buggy.[image]

Could this be a permissions thing to the users group in IIS? This link [Could not load file or assembly 'someProject' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809144/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-someproject-or-one-of-its-dependencies-access) lead me to that question. Any suggestions on how I can get around this?

**Update:** Here are my package sources below:
[image]

Comment: Are there any binding redirects added in your web.config file? are there any being added when you publish the project?

Comment: @MartinUllrich No, I checked in my project file and there is no **AutoGenerateBindingRedirects** property so I am using default value is set to false.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Still nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not replicate your error, but here are some notes how nuget server problems can be solved:

The **packagesPath** key in web.config can be left blank, as you are already using the default folder \Packages.

When deploying to the server, you might find an error in the line of `Access to the path server.cache.bin is denied`. Just create a blank file with that name on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Came here because of the same problem. Funny enough, I had my solution named "Nuget.Server" as well. Changing my Assembly name (under project properties) fixed it. Renamed it to "NugetServer"

[image: Change assembly name under project properties]

Answer (score 0):

If in your Web.config you have a reference to this NuGet.Server package, delete it from the file and try running again. Fairly similar to a BadImageFormatException from a bad reference in the web.config