# NuGet Server cannot find .nupkg package files

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

Okay this is a derivative of [Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Server, Version=2.11.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151843/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-nuget-server-version-2-11-1-0-culture-neutral) seeing as though I couldn't find a solution to that.

I am publishing my Nuget Server project to my Windows 2012 R2 server and pointing to the applicable directory where the files live. The package files exist, as shown below in the screenshot however I keep on getting the below error:

[image]

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Copying file Packages\PackageName.1.0.0.nupkg to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Packages\PackageNameJson.1.0.0.nupkg failed. Could not find file 'Packages\PackageName.1.0.0.nupkg'.    nuget_server_02     0

I have NuGet Server **v2.11.3** installed and my project targets **.NET Framework 4.6**. One thing to note is that the packages themselves are from an earlier version of .NET - most likely 3.5.

This is my **web.config** file:

```
 <add key="packagesPath" value="D:\RootFolder\SubFolder\SolutionNameFolder\ProjectNameFolder\Packages"/>
```

Even after several `Restore NuGet Packages` attempts I am still faced with this dilemma. The one thing I am really struggling to understand is if I point the packagesPath to a local directory, it works and does retrieve the packages however, when I point to the very same project on my server I get this headache.

Previously, in the included link to the related SO question, I could publish but now I can't even get through that stage even though I never made any changes to the project since last working on it. I decided to revisit it today.

**UPDATE:**

I have deleted the bin folder and rebuilt my solution as per [Could not load file or assembly 'someProject' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809144/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-someproject-or-one-of-its-dependencies-access) But it still can't find the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your nuget server and it will show an html file as output (Default.aspx).  You can, of course, modify this file to make it look like anything you want and otherwise change it.  You can't change the way the nuget server service behaves because that is run from a dll.  You should be able to show your repository files using the output page of your nuget server.

I encountered a similar set of errors, and monitored the Event Viewer while I was trying to show the contents of my repository.

The Event Viewer showed that an error was being thrown every time my Nuget Server attempted to list the contents of the packages folder.

Keeping in mind that nuget packages are zip files, and to display the details on the information contained in the nuget packages, the nuget server must unzip them.  If the file is corrupted, the server will throw an error and stop attempting to list the contents of any further files.  This error results in a w3wp.exe crash.  It will be recorded as an ASP.NET error in the Windows->Applications section of the event log.

The cure for me was to delete the contents of the packages folder on my nuget server, and re-up them.

This may be impractical if you have a lot of files in your repository, so any files that were uploaded near the first error shown in the event viewer should be chosen for upload first.

One of the files is likely corrupted.

I would recommend checking out the event viewer on your server, and making sure you have no corrupted files in your repository.

You can view (and edit, to a point) your repository contents with Nuget Package Explorer.  If the file you want to view is corrupted, then it should show an error for that file.  You can then re-up that file, and if the problem is a file problem, this will cure it.

You can also reinstall your nuget server if that fails.  It is somewhat unlikely that the code has been corrupted, but worth a shot.

Good luck.